# Is this a valid method of creating an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading

```
int threads = 5;

pthread_t * thread = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*threads);

            for (i = 0; i < threads; i++){
                int ret = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &foobar_function, NULL);}
```

I'm not in a position to run the code right now. But I saw this as part of an online example and was a little confused by the total lack of square brackets. I'm not great with C.

So does this work for creating an array of threads?

Comment: Assuming you check the malloc() result for NULL, certainly, though I prefer using `(thread+i)` rather than `&thread[i]`, and you can just use `foobar_function`, as its address is implied without an argument list or parenthesis. .

Comment: It's pretty much the same as `pthread_t thread[5];`, so yes. No problem. pthread_create() doesn't care whether the handles are created on the stack or on the heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

`thread` is pointing at a block of memory allocated by `malloc` that is large enough to hold `threads` `pthread_t` objects.

An array of `threads` `pthread_t` objects can be represented in exactly this way.